# Embedding of a Compact Riemann Surface into a Projective Space

Tags: algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

Trying to fill up details of a proof I learnt some time ago: $X$ a compact Riemann surface. We want to show that for large enough degree of a divisor $D$, the map
$X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_D)^*)$, the map being $x\mapsto (f\mapsto f(x))$ is an embedding. I want to understand the one-one part. First, we prove that if deg $D\geq 2g,$ then $\mathcal{O}_D$ is globally generated, i.e. for every $x\in X,\exists f\in H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_D)$ such that
   ord$_x(f)=-D(x).$ Now we choose a divisor $D$ on $X$ with deg $D\geq 2g+1.$ For this $D$ the map $X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}(H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_D)^*)$ is supposed to be one-one. Now this part is not so clear to me.

Let's start anyway. So, suppose we have two points $x\neq y\in X.$ We look at the divisor $D-x$. It has deg $\geq 2g$, so globally generated. So, $\exists f$ with $(f)\geq -D+x$ such that ord$_y(f)=-D(y)$ and                       ord$_x(f)\geq -D(x)+1.$ Now is this enough to say that the map is injective? If yes, why? Can someone please describe the map more appropriately and clear my doubts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am kind of confused. If I recall correctly, the embedding given by the map should be of the form $x\rightarrow [f_1(x), f_2(x)\cdots, f_{n+1}(x)]$, where $f_i$ is a basis for $H^{0}(X, \mathcal{O}_{D})$. The whole is that for very ample line bundles the map separate points. So we have $\dim H^{0}(X, \mathcal{O}(D-x-y))=\dim H^{0}(X, \mathcal{O}(D))-2$ in this case, as we passed the critical range.

Comment: Maybe reading this helps? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_point

Comment: @Bombyxmori yeah, that's the usual embedding one does. I know the proof of that. I am wondering if the map I gave is an embedding.

Comment: I have no idea how is your map even defined in the first place. Can you clarify?

Comment: As I said, even I am trying to recall what I learnt. So, for a fixed $x,$ $f\mapsto f(x)$ is an element of $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_D)^*.$ and we look at it's image in $\mathbb{P}(H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_D)^*)$. This is the map.

Comment: I am not following. Sorry. If you fix $f$, then you map $X$ to a fixed point in the projective space. There is no separation of points.

Comment: No, I am not fixing $f$, for $x\in X$, first we will get an element in the dual of $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_D)$ call it $\tau_x$ which sends any element $f\in H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_D)$ to $f(x)$. Now we at look the image of $\tau_x$ in the projectivization of $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_D)^*$. This is the map.

Comment: Why don't you take any book on Riemann surfaces, or algebraic curves, rather than asking here? This is a totally classic result.

Comment: I know the usual methods to prove this. This was something new I learnt somewhere and I forgot the details. I thought someone might be able to help me.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to help but I am not following. Maybe you can try Math.SE.

Comment: @Bombyxmori thanks anyway.